# apt-get linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-72-generic problem

Tags: apt, package-management

Hey I have a problem with installing/uninstalling packages, since a few days ago apt-get wants to remove the package `linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-72-generic`, but every time it tries it just freezes, the same if I use `dpkg` to uninstall it, I can't do anything. I use Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: There is no output at all?

Comment: No, It just hangs there but sometimes It gives a dpkg sub process error, I can't even cancel It with Ctrl-C

Comment: All apt terminal output leading up to the freeze is the minimum we need. Summaries ("a dpkg subprocess error") lack the detail we need to offer any help.

Comment: I tried recovery mode too with the same result, maybe I should reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Before reinstalling - boot from a LiveUSB, check logs in /var/log, and check for hardware faults on your HDD and RAM.